# Making a Common Button Widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Im making a common Button widget that have three states Active / Disable / Loading.
im managing the status from the place where I use the ButtonWidget.
I'll post what I did so far.
when I try to run the button widget it gets an error. namely

> The following assertion was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:
> _ButtonWidgetState#ab5a5(ticker active) was disposed with an active Ticker.

> _ButtonWidgetState created a Ticker via its SingleTickerProviderStateMixin, but at the time dispose() was called on the mixin, that Ticker was still active. The Ticker must be disposed before calling super.dispose().

I imagine this is due the to animation I already have in my button widget.
can anyone help me to overcome this.?
would be really helpful.

**ButtonWidget**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);
const TextStyle tButtonMedium = TextStyle(
  fontSize: 16.0,
  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
);
enum eButtonType {
  bText,
  bIcon,
  bIconText,
}

enum eButtonState {
  bActive,
  bDisable,
  bLoading,
}
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class CustomColors {
  static const Color grey100 = Color(0xFFF0F0F0);
  static const Color grey600 = Color(0xFFAFAFAF);
  static const Color mWhite = Color(0xFFFFFFFF);
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  var _isLoading = false;
  eButtonState? btnState;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _makeActive();
    super.initState();
   
  }

  void _makeActive() {
    Future.delayed(
      const Duration(seconds: 5),
      () => setState(() {
        btnState = eButtonState.bActive;
      }),
    );
  }

  void _onSubmit() {
    setState(() {
      btnState = eButtonState.bLoading;
    });
    Future.delayed(
        const Duration(seconds: 10),
        () => setState(() {
              btnState = eButtonState.bActive;
            }));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ButtonWidget(
      key: UniqueKey(),
      onPressed: () {
        _onSubmit();
      },
      btnColor: Colors.white,
      borderColor: Colors.blue,
      textColor: Colors.blue,
      text: "Save",
      eButtonState: btnState,
      eButtonType: eButtonType.bIconText,
      iconData: Icons.save_alt,
    );
  }
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class ButtonWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  //
  final String? text;
  final Color? btnColor;
  final Color? borderColor;
  final Color? textColor;
  final Function? onPressed;
  // final bool? isActive;
  final eButtonType;
  final eButtonState;
  final IconData? iconData;

  const ButtonWidget({
    Key? key,
    this.text,
    this.btnColor,
    this.borderColor,
    this.textColor,
    this.eButtonType,
    this.iconData,
    @required this.eButtonState,
    @required this.onPressed,
    // @required this.isActive,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ButtonWidgetState createState() => _ButtonWidgetState();
}

class _ButtonWidgetState extends State<ButtonWidget>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late double _scale;
  late AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(
        milliseconds: 100,
      ),
      upperBound: 0.1,
    )..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }

  void buttonHandler() {
    _controller.forward();
    Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 50), () {
      _controller.reverse();
    });
    Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 50), () {
      widget.onPressed!();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _scale = 1 - _controller.value;
    return Transform.scale(
      scale: _scale,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        style: TextButton.styleFrom(
          elevation: widget.eButtonState == eButtonState.bActive ? 2.0 : 0.0,
          primary: widget.eButtonState == eButtonState.bActive
              ? widget.btnColor!
              : CustomColors.grey600,
          backgroundColor: widget.eButtonState == eButtonState.bActive
              ? widget.btnColor!
              : CustomColors.grey100,
          minimumSize: const Size(80.0, 50.0),
          maximumSize: const Size(double.infinity, 50.0),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            side: BorderSide(
              color: widget.eButtonState == eButtonState.bActive
                  ? widget.borderColor!
                  : CustomColors.grey100,
              width: 2,
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
          ),
          splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory,
        ),
        onPressed: () => widget.eButtonState == eButtonState.bActive
            ? buttonHandler()
            : null,
        child: widget.eButtonState == eButtonState.bLoading
            ? const CircularProgressIndicator(
                color: CustomColors.grey600,
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              )
            : (widget.eButtonType == eButtonType.bText
                ? Text(
                    widget.text!,
                    style: tButtonMedium.copyWith(
                      color: widget.eButtonState == eButtonState.bActive
                          ? widget.textColor!
                          : CustomColors.grey600,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    textScaleFactor: 1.0,
                  )
                : (widget.eButtonType == eButtonType.bIconText)
                    ? Row(
                        // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: [
                          Icon(
                            widget.iconData,
                            color: widget.eButtonState == eButtonState.bActive
                                ? widget.textColor
                                : CustomColors.grey600,
                          ),
                          Spacer(),
                          Text(
                            widget.text!,
                            style: tButtonMedium.copyWith(
                              color: widget.eButtonState == eButtonState.bActive
                                  ? widget.textColor!
                                  : CustomColors.grey600,
                            ),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            textScaleFactor: 1.0,
                          ),
                          Spacer(),
                        ],
                      )
                    : Icon(
                        widget.iconData,
                        color: widget.eButtonState == eButtonState.bActive
                            ? CustomColors.mWhite
                            : CustomColors.grey600,
                      )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can make your own answer for the question instead of editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get to fixed by simply doing

```
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

If anyone wish to have a common button widget. please feel free to use this code. and I appreciate if veterans can guide to improve this widget. cheers